# Strange border on autocomplete dropdown

Tags: css, reactjs

I got some weird border on the dropdown of an autocomplete input. Tried it on other people computer and they don't see the same issue. Anyone came across this strange behavior before? It's a ReactJS component. The reason why I don't post the code is because this only happen to my Chrome browser and not to other people. Checked my Chrome extension, there's nothing related to CSS modification or anything.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code for this.

Comment: Those are scrollbars. You can hide them with `overflow:hidden;` on the dropdown element. Though you may want to just do `overflow-x:hidden;`(in order to hide only the horizontal scrollbar) because if the list is taller than the height of the dropdown, users will not be able to scroll to the other options in the dropdown.

Comment: @APAD but it only happens to "my" browser though, so I don't think it's a coding issue?

Comment: Different browsers have different default stylings. Those are definitely scrollbars, not borders, and the CSS I provided above is how you can hide them.